# Javascript copy url link to clipboard using navigator

Tags: javascript, clipboard, navigator

I am trying to copy url link using below code

```
let text = 'click here'
let hrefLink = `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">${text}</a>`;

if (navigator && navigator.clipboard != undefined) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(hrefLink);
}
```

If I am using above code the pasted text will be link like

"`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">click here</a>`"

But I am trying to paste the text like this "[click here](https://stackoverflow.com)" I can see some examples using `document.exec()`. If somebody suggest using `navigator.clipboard` it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your example tries to copy to the clipboard using `navigator.clipboard.writeText`, which is only capable of writing plain text. If you'd like to embed a link, you may want to try writing HTML instead, via `navigator.clipboard.write`, and the `'text/html'` type.

For an example of how to write HTML using the Clipboard API, see this [Safari blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/10855/async-clipboard-api/#post-10855:%7E:text=The%20following%20example%20uses%20clipboard.write%20to,both%20plain%20text%20and%20HTML%20representations) example, or the source of this [HTML demo site](https://hyper-silly-cross.glitch.me/).